# Error while creating a Mapwize Xamarin binding from Cocoapods

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mapbox, objective-sharpie

I am trying to create a Xamarin wrapper for MapwizeForMapbox (1.4.2).

The first step works fine :

```
>sharpie pod init iphoneos11.4 MapwizeForMapbox
```

First issue: I have to modify **./Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/Mapbox.framework/Info.plist** and define **iphoneos11.4** for **DTSDKName**

Then I try to create the binding project, but that were I'm stuck.

```
>sharpie pod bind

... (Most of the output is not relevant)
Parsing 1 header files...
While building module 'MapwizeForMapbox' imported from /private/var/folders/mh/6zg82ll54dqb88336hy5rt6c0000gn/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/c772554be7d445d3bc547872f8136c50.h:1:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/aktar/Documents/src/BindingProjects/MapWize/Pods/MapwizeForMapbox/MapwizeForMapbox.framework/Headers/MapwizeForMapbox.h:12:
/Users/aktar/Documents/src/BindingProjects/MapWize/Pods/MapwizeForMapbox/MapwizeForMapbox.framework/Headers/MapwizePlugin.h:4:9: fatal error: 'IndoorLocation/IndoorLocation.h' file not found
#import <IndoorLocation/IndoorLocation.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/mh/6zg82ll54dqb88336hy5rt6c0000gn/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/c772554be7d445d3bc547872f8136c50.h:1:9: fatal error: could not build module 'MapwizeForMapbox'
@import MapwizeForMapbox;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Have anyone out there ever had this issue ? How can I make it pass this ?

When imported into a native iOS project the library works just fine.